# Android MediaCodec decoding of raw h.264

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

I'm having a very difficult time with MediaCodc.  I've used it previously to decode a raw h.264 stream and learned a significant amount.  At least I thought I had.

My stream is h.264 in Annex B format.  Looking at the raw data, the structure of my NAL packet code types are as follows:

```
[0x09][0x09][0x06] and then 8 packets of [0x21].
[0x09][0x09][0x27][0x28][0x06] and then 8 packets of [0x21].
```

This is not how I am receiving them.  I am attempting to build a complete Access Unit from these raw NAL unit types.

First thing that is strange to me is the double [0x09] which is the Access Unit Delimiter packet.  I am pretty sure the h.264 document specifies only 1 AUD per Access Unit.  BTW, I am able to record the raw data and play it using ffmpeg with, and without, the extra AUD.  For now, I am detecting this message and stripping the first one off before sending the entire Access Unit to the MediaCodec.

Second thing is, I have hardcoded the SPS/PPS byte array messages [0x27/0x28] and I am setting these in the MediaFormat used to initialize the MediaCodec, similar to:

```
format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap( mySPS ));
format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap( myPPS ));
```

My video stream provider vendor tells me the video is 1280 x 720, however, when I convert it to an mp4 file, the metadata says its 960 x 720.  Another oddity.

Changing these different parameters around, I am still unable to get a valid buffer index in my Thread that processes the decoder output (dequeueOutputBuffer returns -1).  I have also varied the timeout for this to no avail.  If I manually set the SPS/PPS as the first packet NOT using the example above, I do get the -3 "output buffers have changed" which is meaningless since I am using API 20.  But everything else I get returned is -1.

I've read about the Emulation Prevention Byte encoding of h.264.  I am able to strip this byte out and send to the MediaCodec.  Doesn't seem to make a difference.  Also, the documentation for MediaCodec doesn't explicitly say if the code is expecting the EPB to be stripped out or not ... ?

Other than the video frame resolution, the only other thing that is different than my previous success is the existence of the SEI packet type [0x06].  I'm not sure if I should be doing something special with this or not?

I know there are a number of folks who have used MediaCodec have had issues with it, mostly because the documentation is not very good.  Can anyone offer any other advice as to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Might need @lajosmolnar (http://stackoverflow.com/users/2884545/lajos-molnar) for this one.

Comment: Considering the extra AUD, I wouldn't be surprised to learn the video provider isn't supplying correct data, according to the spec.  I wonder if I need to look at the slice frame numbers and see if they are being spanned across NAL AUD packets or not.

Comment: @fadden Maybe you can help me with a question?  I'm parsing between the Access Unit Delimiters now.  When I look at the size of the complete access units, they are much smaller than the previous version of my video supplier.  I am sure I am parsing them correctly because my buffer/parsing code is the same.  The previous version (that worked) is smaller in resolution.  Have you ever seen a case where parsing between the AUD packets does NOT constitute a full frame?  The frame_num markers are the same between AUDs .. maybe another variable I need to look at and queue up multiple packets?

Comment: sorry, I don't know H.264 that well.